# MySQL Select by String in a Column -- PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select records from a MySQL table that have a specified year in the column `pay_month`.  Entries in that column are like **September 2013** or **November 2013**.  I believe I need to use `LIKE` in the query, but I don't know how.

Here's what I have...

```
$history_query = "SELECT * FROM session_history where tutors_id = '" . $tutors_id ."' and pay month LIKE '2013' ORDER BY date_added DESC";
```

Any ideas on how to get this working?

Comment: Why not use a date(time) or timestamp format for storing such stuff?

Comment: You didn't tell us the structure of the table (in particular the type of the pay_month field)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your pay_month column is a string, it looks like your code is mostly correct, but you're missing an underscore in pay month... oops. Also add in a % to match wildcard.

try:

```
$history_query = "SELECT * FROM session_history where tutors_id = '" . $tutors_id ."' and pay_month LIKE '%2013' ORDER BY date_added DESC";
```

Answer (score 0):

If that is a Date or DateTime column you could always use > and < so something like

```
pay_month < 2014-00-00 AND pay_month > 2013-00-00
```